# beginner Python class

Tags: python, class, button

I currently have this code, that if the ToggleButton is pressed I want it to say

```
ToggleButton was pressed
```

and then state whether the ToggleButton is on or off (it is on by default, if the button is pressed it will be turned off) I want to do this through the state being True or False, but I'm not sure how to do this.
Any help would be appreciated

```
class Button(object):

    def __init__(self, text = "button"):
        self.label = text

    def press(self):
        print("{0} was pressed".format(self.label))
class ToggleButton(Button):

   def __init__(self, text="ToggleButton", state=True):
        self.label = text
```

For example I want

```
b = ToggleButton()
b.press()
```

To return:

```
ToggleButton was pressed
ToggleButton is now OFF
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add a `self.state` variable:

```
class ToggleButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, text="ToggleButton", state=True):
        super(ToggleButton, self).__init__(text) 
        self.state = state

    def press(self):
        super(ToggleButton, self).press()
        self.state = not self.state
        print('ToggleButton is now', 'ON' if self.state else 'OFF')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the other answers have answered your question fully yet, so I'll give it a shot. You've already got your class hierarchy set up just fine; what you need to do now is override the `press` method to handle the new data (toggling the current state). This is very simple! Consider the following class:

```
class ToggleButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, text="ToggleButton", state=True):
        self.label = text
        self.state = state

    def press(self):
        # Call the superclass press() method
        # Note that pre-Python 3, the call needs to be super(ToggleButton,self)
        super().press()

        # Toggle state
        self.state = not self.state

        # Print current state
        print('{0} is now {1}'.format(self.label,'ON' if self.state else 'OFF'))
```

The new `press` method only does three things:

- First, it calls the `press` method of the superclass (`Button`). This prevents you having to duplicate the code to print "Button was pressed", or any other code you might end up putting in the base `Button` class!
- Second, it toggles the current state. This part doesn't need much explanation!
- Finally, it prints out a message about the new state of the button.

That's all there is to it! I hope this clears the process up for you a bit.